# Passenger error #3 when installing django application in DirectAdmin host

Tags: python, django, directadmin

When i was installed django app in DirectAdmin, i found error like this in when i go to my domain [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87DDv.png),
how to fix that?

i've tried finding solution, but there is just solution to fixing to root file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.